# gcc undefined reference to header function

Tags: gcc, undefined-reference

I know there have been a lot of such topics, but I didn't found the answer, really. There's nothing that isn't working.

I am compiling file

```
gcc   -std=c99 -Lmem xx.c
```

in the file there is

```
#include "include/memory.h"
#include <stdlib.h>


void main(){
    meminit(100);
}
```

and in memory.h

```
#include "private.h"
#pragma once
MEMI * memdiag();

void meminit(int block_number);

void * memalloc(int desired_size);

void memfree(void * ptr);
```

the folder contains libmem.a, and headers, yet I'm getting error

```
/tmp/ccSJ4trm.o: In function `main':
xx.c:(.text+0xa): undefined reference to `meminit'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I would be very grateful if You helped me, tomorrow I have to hand in the project.

Comment: From the code you've posted, you're declaring `meminit` but not defining it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to read some tutorials about using GCC.

You might want to try to compile and link with with

```
gcc -std=c99 -Wall -g xx.c -L. -lmem
```

(assuming your current *directory* [not folder] i.e. the `.` in  `-L.` contains a `libmem.a` or `libmem.so*` library)

BTW, order of program arguments to `gcc` matters a big lot!

Comment: Wow man! Thank you very much, I didn't know about -L. option, neither I've seen it.