# gcc undefined reference to header of multiple files

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-errors

I have a sample code `temp.c`:

```
     #include "win.h"
```

`win.h` is in `/home/me/Documents/Code/libs/TUI/win.h` and has all the declared functions
which functions are defined in some files in `/home/me/Documents/Code/libs/TUI/win/[lots of files].c` which every file starts with

```
    #include "../win.h"
    //functions
```

So while using `gcc -I /home/me/Documents/Code/libs/TUI /home/me/Documents/Code/temp.c -o /home/me/Documents/Code/temp`, gcc returns every function used in `temp.c` declared in `win.h` as undefined

Exact output:

```
gcc -g -I/home/me/Documents/Code/libs/TUI /home/me/Documents/Code/temp.c -o /home/pk/Documents/Code/temp

/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cc4berEn.o: in function `main':
/home/me/Documents/Code/temp.c:8: undefined reference to `innit'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/me/Documents/Code/temp.c:11: undefined reference to `newTable'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/me/Documents/Code/temp.c:13: undefined reference to `tableSetHeaders'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/me/Documents/Code/temp.c:35: undefined reference to `tableAppendRow'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/me/Documents/Code/temp.c:45: undefined reference to `printTable'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

### notes

- Using `-I /home/me/Documents/Code/libs/TUI/win.h` returns `fatal error: win.h: No such file or directory 3 | #include "win.h"`
- `/home/me/Documents/Code/libs/TUI` is a folder
- Writing every source file's name is not an option
- Already tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22642235/gcc-undefined-reference-to-header-function)
- `-g` for debug

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Comment: The argument to `-I` should be a directory, not a file. It's the directory to search for header files.

Comment: "Undefined reference" is a linking problem, not a problem with the header.

Comment: When you say "undefined", did the _compiler_ think the symbol was undefined (i.e. it could _not_ find a declaration in a `.h` file)? Or, did the _linker_ say it was undefined (i.e. It could _not_ find a given symbol in any `.dll` in the library search path? You probably need (e.g.) `-L` followed by something `-L /home/me/Documents/Code/libs` or `-L /home/me/Documents/Code/libs/TUI` You may also need `-rpath` in lieu of `-L`

Comment: From your link, it's _definitely_ a link time problem. you probably want: `-L /home/me/Documents/Code/libs -lmem`. This assumes that `libmem.a` has a full path of: `/home/me/Documents/Code/libs/libmem.a` Adjust the directory to suit your actual directory hierarchy.

Comment: @CraigEstey if a do `gcc -g -L /home/me/Documents/Code/libs/TUI -lmem /home/me/Documents/Code/temp.c -o /home/pk/Documents/Code/temp` I get `/home/me/Documents/Code/temp.c:3:10: fatal error: win.h: No such file or directory
    3 | #include "win.h"
      |          ^~~~~~~
compilation terminated.`

Comment: @PacifiK: headers and libraries are different files, independent of each other. `-I` and `-L` are independent options. Compiling and linking are independent tasks, although gcc is capable of doing both (in order, independently) with a single command invocation. Often, if you need an `-I` option to compile, you will also need a `-L` option (and several `-l` options) in order to link. But not always.

Comment: You need _both_ `-I` and `-L`: `-I /home/me/Documents/Code/libs/TUI -L /home/me/Documents/Code/libs/TUI -lmem`. More generally, if you had `/foo/win.h` and `/bar/libmem.a`, you'd need: `-I /foo -L /bar -lmem`. Again, adjust directories to match the actual placement of `win.h` and `libmem.a`